# Videos have blue faces when I play them

Tags: video, video-player

I started the video and it says it has no codex and it can search for it(it looked cool) and it has downloaded them and video works great, but for some reason all the faces on videos I'm watching are blue, how to make them not blue?(I bet its a common problem).

P.S. I'm not prejudiced against aliens, I just don't like them.

Comment: wich media player are you using ?
DId you try for example play the video in VLC ? ( `sudo apt-get install vlc` ) or mplayer ?

Comment: @Luciano Facchinelli  mplayer, but i also tried some other player at i has the same problem. I think its because of installed codecs :(

Comment: Are you watching Blue Man Group? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm running 12.04 LTS with a Nvidea GeForce 8400M GS (512 MB). SMPlayer (vers. 0.81) is my default playback app. & Totem Movie Player 3.0.1 (Movie Player using GStreamer 0.10.36)

All movies opened from hdd show "blue faces".
Yet sometimes when opening "Nvidea XServer Settings", the next video I play is in normal colors. (only once...opening the same movie again will show blue faces again)

FIX :

Download and install "Sysinfo" app. and open it.
Select "Nvidea" - "Nvidea Display Settings".
Under "X Screen 0" select "X Server Xvideo Settings".
Slide the "Hue" controller all the way down to zero.

If this didn't help (in my case no option to save this setting, but only the option to "quit" Nvidea XServer Settings"), open Totem Movie Player ;

Open the video and check for "blue faces". Let the video continue playing.
Go to "edit", "Preferences", "Display" : Slide the "Hue" controller to zero.
While you're sliding the Hue down, you will see the colors change to normal.

In my case the changes made in Totem Movie Player where also adapted in the SMPlayer and all videos are playing in normal colors now.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I did the nvidea hue setting and it fixed it for me!

Answer (score 6):

In the bug report that Clausi links there are quite a lot of workarounds.

This tip from Le Glun de net looks like the best aproach to me.

> If you have this bug (blue and red
>   color in video are invert) and you
>   have a nvidia, you don't have to
>   install or uninstall any software.
>   Just launch the "nvidia X server
>   settings", choose your screen (X
>   screen 0), "Xserver video settings",
>   "Reset hardware defaults".

Note that it seems to correct itself as soon as you open the Nvidia setting for some people.

Comment: i do have Nvidia, I will try this later at home, thx.

Comment: it did not help, but thx.

Answer (score 4):

this seems to have a couple of different possible causes.

Most likely you can fix this by just using a different output method in mplayer.
try:

```
mplayer -vo xv movie.avi
```

or

```
mplayer -vo gl movie.avi
```

There are similar flags for other players like vlc, and I'm sure it's in the settings page of your favourite GUI also. (I know it's in vlc and smplayer at least)

Comment: "mplayer -vo gl movie.avi" has worked, thx a lot :D

Answer (score 4):

"  1. Open gstreamer-properties (alt+f2, enter gstreamer-properties)

1. Change to the video tab
2. Change the default output plugin to "custom"
3. Place the following command in the bottom box: videobalance hue=-1 ! autovideosink
4. Close the box and enjoy your now correct colour "

Answer (score 3):

From https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-settings/+bug/395476:

1. open totem via Applications > Sound & Video > Movie Player
2. open the preferences window via Edit > Preferences
3. select the Display tab
4. click the Reset to Defaults button

Comment: thx for cool idea, but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg` if it doesn't exist

Add the lines or change values to:

```
EnableLinuxHWVideoDecode=1
OverrideGPUValidation=true
```

Solution from: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/974620

Answer (score 2):

For me it whas The video output i had set to Directx (direct draw). I changed it to Open GL and it whas gone. Seems Direct Draw actualy draw the skins blue. Kinda funny real life smurf people. Im using Vlc player and had lots of trouble Turned on Gpu for lagging and Hardware acceleration. Video codec to Open Gl. Still not working good but faces are not blue anymore and is best i can get right know.

Comment: Ok so now i chainged the buffer to 3500ms. And now it actually works how it should. No blue faces and no lag. Hope it will be like this also tomorow when i try again

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried another media player? which one are your using?

I would try to play the video in **VLC** ?

```
 sudo apt-get install vlc
```

or **mplayer**

Comment: mplayer, but i also tried some other player at i has the same problem. I think its because of installed codecs :(

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the rest of suggestions, which I'd follow, if everything fails try installing latest nvidia drivers (if you're using them)