# Why are all the people colored blue in my videos?

Tags: nvidia, video, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Video and blue faces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20319/video-and-blue-faces)

After installing a fresh version of ubuntu 11.10 on my pc (64bit version, intel quad core, Nvidia GPU, installed 3rd party drivers and codecs) I've tried to watch a movie.

I've open the movie both with vlc and with movie player and something with the colors didn't seems right, It took me few more seconds until few people started to appear on the screen but their body color was smurf blue.

It also happened on my pc when I've upgraded from 9.10 to 10.04 and seems like opening the video with video player -> properties -> display -> reset to default solved the problem, but that was a temporary fix and I had to retake these steps on each restart.

This time, It seems that nothing helps, and all I get is Human-like Smurfs.

Any Idea how to solve it?

Comment: Lol @ the title xD

I suggest you click the "This affects me" button in this bug report and let the people know in a comment that this porblem hasn't been entirely solved. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-settings/+bug/395476

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give this a try: http://www.wiredrevolution.com/ubuntu/fix-blue-tinted-video-in-ubuntu